# passing variables from one function to another function: python

Tags: python, variables

---

I have two variables `num_of_plants` and `num_of_plants2` that i want to pass the the `total()` but I receive the following error:

> num_of_plants is undefined

```
def outer_flowerbed(length,spacing):
    square_area = length ** 2
    side = length/2
    side_ba= (side**2)+(side**2)
    side_c=math.sqrt(side_ba)
    fill_area = side_c**2
    outer_bed = square_area - fill_area
    outer_triangles = outer_bed/4
    conversion = spacing / 12
    num_of_plants = outer_triangles/conversion**2
    print "number of plants in each triangular bed: ",int(num_of_plants)
    return num_of_plants
def circle_area(length,spacing):
    radius = length/4
    a = radius**2 * math.pi
    conversion = spacing/12
    num_of_plants2 = a/conversion**2
    print "number of plants the circle garden has: ",int(num_of_plants2)
    return num_of_plants2
def total(a,b):
    add = a*4 + b
    print "Total plants: ",add
```

Comment: That's just a bunch of function definitions, your code does not say anything.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that would produce that error.

Comment: Can you provide an example that we can test, so that we can help you debug?  Right now it's just function definitions, but if we had example arguments for the functions, we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to find the number of plants needed for a garden like

[image]

so here is an over-engineered solution (using an abstract base class and two subclasses):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from math import pi

INCHES_PER_FOOT = 12.

def get_float(prompt):
    """
    Prompt until a float value is entered, then return it
    """
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

class PlantedArea(ABC):
    spacing = 0.5

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, name, *args):
        self.name = name
        self.args = args

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def area(self):
        return 1

    @property
    def plants(self):
        """
        Return the number of plants which can be placed in `area`
          with `spacing` separation between each plant.

        Note: this is the theoretical maximum number, assuming
          a square planting grid; the actual number needed
          may vary slightly depending on the shape of the border
        """
        return int(self.area / self.spacing**2)

class TriangleArea(PlantedArea):
    def __init__(self, name, width, height):
        self.name   = name
        self.width  = width
        self.height = height

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.height / 2

class CircleArea(PlantedArea):
    def __init__(self, name, radius):
        self.name   = name
        self.radius = radius

    @property
    def area(self):
        return pi * self.radius ** 2

def main():
    length  = get_float("What is the garden width (in feet)? ")
    spacing = get_float("What is your plant spacing (in inches)? ") / INCHES_PER_FOOT

    PlantedArea.spacing = spacing
    beds = [
        TriangleArea("NW corner", length/2, length/2),
        TriangleArea("NE corner", length/2, length/2),
        TriangleArea("SW corner", length/2, length/2),
        TriangleArea("SE corner", length/2, length/2),
        CircleArea  ("center",    length/4)
    ]

    total_plants = 0
    for bed in beds:
        plants = bed.plants
        print("The {} bed needs {} plants".format(bed.name, plants))
        total_plants += plants

    print("The whole garden needs a total of {} plants.".format(total_plants))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
What is the garden width (in feet)? 20
What is your plant spacing (in inches)? 6

The NW corner bed needs 200 plants
The NE corner bed needs 200 plants
The SW corner bed needs 200 plants
The SE corner bed needs 200 plants
The center bed needs 314 plants
The whole garden needs 1114 plants.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions assuming they work, return values that your two variables represent. So if you just use the functions directly as args to your total() then it should work.

```
total(outer_flowerbed(10,2), circle_area(10,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

What's important to note is that num_of_plants and num_of_plants2 are local to your function and cannot be called outside the function. However, since you are returning the values, why not just add the results of the two functions together. So your main function would look like:

```
def main():
    length = #whatever you have here
    spacing = #whatever you have here
    x,y = outer_flowerbed(length, spacing),circle_area(length,spacing)
    total(x,y)
```